# How to implement drag and drop in MahApps Metro Layout

Tags: mahapps.metro

Can anyone please suggest me on how to implement drag and drop of tiles in MahApps Metro layout. Thanks..

Comment: have you found the solution? if yes, plz share it, i am having same issue

Answer (score 3):

We have had success using another of punker76's libraries.

Its lightweight and easy to implement!

GitHub
https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

NuGet
https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/